# How to generate PDF on Windows Phone in C#

Tags: windows-phone, win-universal-app

I need to generate a PDF from my Windows universal app with the following requirements.

- Break the pages at proper places
- Show background colors
- Show the borders and set heights properly
- Show images (if needed)
- Add spacing
- Different sizes of fonts
- Show a boxes
- Different colored borders and lines.

I found following links.

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Apitron.PDF.Kit.Mobile/
- http://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/overview

I just need to know any other 3rd party solutions or any other ways to generate a PDF from windows universal app.

Comment: You can use print feature to print a uwp page as PDF.Details see [Printing from your app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app).  Demo is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing).

Comment: Thank you @Sunteen for reply, but we are not going to print the content of the uwp page, we have to add more content.